# Spring Application Failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app with many beans. In one bean, if there is an exception in the bean's constructor, the application fails to start. In a different bean, an exception in the constructor does **not** cause the application to fail to start. Failing to start is the desired behavior. What is the difference between the two beans? How do I get the behavior to be the same?

Comment: Code snippet, please.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: not sure a code snippet would be helpful - question is more theoretical - what causes spring to fail the application in certain instances and not in other instance

Comment: @Jewels there can be many reasons on why a failure of particular bean is not causing the application to fail on start. So share some code snippets from your app.